# Unsuccessful upgrade from 11.10 to 12.4 LTS leads to black screen with cursor blinking

Tags: grub2, upgrade, graphics, text-mode

During the upgrade from 11.10 to 12.4, I got stuck on a screen with background image, and nothing else.

I restarted the computer, and after GRUB menu, screen gets black with cursor blinking.

I've tried getting into text mode, by removing `quiet splash`, and by adding `text`, but it leads to the same black screen.

So, I cant get to both text or graphical mode. I'm stuck on GRUB menu. What can I do to get it working again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I restarted, the upgrade was interrupted, and therefore I couldn't boot on the last kernel.

I had to boot the previous kernel on text mode, and resume upgrade via `sudo apt-get upgrade`. At some point it passed me a command using `dpkg` that resumed the instalation.